# Rail map method to generate array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, enumerator

I have an array of hash and I am generating one array of hash using map. I can generate array of has when my array have two values but I want to generate same kind of result using one array.

I have an array which is:

```
 b =  [
    {
    id: 1,
    State: "Andhra Pradesh",
    Rural_Oct_16_Index_Final: 137.5,
    Rural_Oct_17_Index_Provisional: 143,
    Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage: 4,
    Urban_Oct_16_Index_Final: 131.7,
    Urban_Oct_17_Index_Provisional: 135.6,
    Urban_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage: 3,
    Combined_Oct_16_Index_Final: 135.4,
    Combined_Oct_17_Index_Provisional: 140.3,
    Combined_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage: 3.6,
    created_at: "2018-08-30T05:01:58.000Z",
    updated_at: "2018-08-30T05:01:58.000Z"
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    State: "Bihar",
    Rural_Oct_16_Index_Final: 135.7,
    Rural_Oct_17_Index_Provisional: 138.7,
    Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage: 2.2,
    Urban_Oct_16_Index_Final: 128.2,
    Urban_Oct_17_Index_Provisional: 131.4,
    Urban_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage: 2.5,
    Combined_Oct_16_Index_Final: 134.6,
    Combined_Oct_17_Index_Provisional: 137.6,
    Combined_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage: 2.2,
    created_at: "2018-08-30T05:01:58.000Z",
    updated_at: "2018-08-30T05:01:58.000Z"
    }
]
```

And I using this code:

```
 b.map do |el|
       { y: el['Rural_Oct_16_Index_Final'], label: el['State'] }
  end
```

I am getting this result:

```
 [
   {
     y: 3.6,
     label: "Andhra Pradesh"
    },
    {
   y: 2.2,
  label: "Bihar"
  }
 ]
```

So my question is when my array has just one value like:

```
  [
    {
    id: 1,
    State: "Andhra Pradesh",
    Rural_Oct_16_Index_Final: 137.5,
    Rural_Oct_17_Index_Provisional: 143,
    Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage: 4,
    Urban_Oct_16_Index_Final: 131.7,
    Urban_Oct_17_Index_Provisional: 135.6,
    Urban_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage: 3,
    Combined_Oct_16_Index_Final: 135.4,
    Combined_Oct_17_Index_Provisional: 140.3,
    Combined_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage: 3.6,
    created_at: "2018-08-30T05:01:58.000Z",
    updated_at: "2018-08-30T05:01:58.000Z"
    }
]
```

And using map method I want a result like this:

```
 [
   {
     y: 2.2,
     label: "Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage"
    },
    {
   y: 128.2,
  label: "Urban_Oct_16_Index_Final"
  }
]
```

When I am using this code:

```
     b.map do |el|
    { y: el['Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage'], label: "Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage" },
     { y: el['Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage'], label: "Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage" }
end
```

I am getting this error when I remove comma I am getting one one result with no error.

Is there any way to make this work using map method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b.flat_map do |el|
  [{ y: el['Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage'], label: "Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage" },
     { y: el['Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage'], label: "Rural_Inflation_Rate_in_percentage" }]
end
```